# Lookup between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have several lists that I would like to match and operate values among them.  For simplicity assume I have these two lists:

```
l1 = Transpose[{Range[1980, 2010, 1], Range[31]}]
l2 = {{1990, 1,100}, {2000, 2,200}, {2010, 3,300}}
```

I would like to divide the third column of l2 by the second column in l1 matching the year in both lists.

I should obtain:

```
l3 = {{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}
```

How can I set a function to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Lookup` says it all... ;)

```
lookuptable = AssociationThread[l1[[All, 1]], l1[[All, 2]]];
l3 = l2;
l3[[All, 3]] /= Lookup[lookuptable, l2[[All, 1]]];
l3
```

> {{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}

**Remark on performance:**

It may sound a bit over the top for this tiny usage example, but I had very intentionall written this exactly like it is now: using `AssociationThread`, with a dedicated copy operation, and without `Map`-like constructs. Here is why:

Suppose that`l1` is of length `m` and that `l2` is of length `n`. A naive lookup would cost you `m n` comparisons. This gets *slow* for large `m` and `n`. If you have to do many lookups, then it pays off quite soon to build a dedicated search data structure (e.g., a binary tree) for `l1`. Then you can boil down the runtime cost to something like $O(|\log(m)| \, n)$. That's precisely what I meant to do by using `AssociationThread[l1[[All, 1]], l1[[All, 2]]]`: It generates an `Association`, whose constructor builds up precisely such a search data structure. Morever, I used this precise syntax (I could also have used `AssociationThread@@Transpose[l1]` in order to not unpack any arrays (which can also have some mildly negative effect on runtime).

The reason why I do not use `Map`-like constructs is that they are - albeit being backed up by jit-compilation - still way slower than an ordinary compiled loop written in *C/C++*. The creators of `Lookup` knew that, too, so they implemented an overload of `Lookup` that can look up many keys in the association all at once (by implementing the loop over the keys as a *C/C++* loop). So we get the looping for free. Moreover, if the type of keys allows (we use simple arrays of base types like integers here), then `Lookup` picks a code branch that does *not* involve the pattern matcher. The pattern matcher *is* very handy, but its power comes at a high performance cost.

The creators of `Lookup` where also kind enough to return us a packed array, if possible! So in principle, you can proceed with your computations with packed arrays if those computations allow it.
In the example here, this does not happen, because exact rational numbers cannot be stored in packed arrays. But supposing that `l3` and `Values[lookuptable]` where packed arrays of machine precision reals, then after

```
l3[[All, 3]] /= Lookup[lookuptable, l2[[All, 1]]];
```

the array `l3` were still packed (at least if no division by zero occurs). Moreover, `l3[[All, 3]] /= [...]` would use a more efficient code branch that implements this with compiled `C/C++` loops of division on piecewise contiguous memory. At least for floating point data, piecewise contiguous divisions are easy to vectorize for the compiler, so it very likely that the employed library function *is* vectorized.

So the point was to write it to always perform well - and to perform *very well* in certain common situations, e.g., involving packed arrays.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.  Gracias Tocayo!  worked fine.

Comment: I'm always glad to be of help! You're welcome!

Comment: For brevity, likely at the cost of some performance, you can eliminate `AssociationThread` and use simply `Lookup[Rule @@@ l1, l2[[All, 1]]]`

Comment: I never sacrifice performance for brevity (if I can help it). Well, almost never. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
Cases[GatherBy[Join[l1, l2], First], {x_, y_} :> {x[[1]], y[[2]], y[[3]]/x[[2]]}]
```

> {{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}

Answer (score 4):

```
a = Transpose[{Range[1980, 2010, 1], Range[31]}];

b = {{1990, 1, 100}, {2000, 2, 200}, {2010, 3, 300}}

MapThread[{Splice @ Most[#1], Last[#1 / #2]&, {b, Lookup[Rule @@@ a, First /@ b]}]
```

{{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}

Answer (score 4):

```
l1 = Transpose[{Range[1980, 2010, 1], Range[31]}]
l2 = {{1990, 1, 100}, {2000, 2, 200}, {2010, 3, 300}}
```

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
lut = Rule @@@ l1;
#/{1, 1, Lookup[lut, First@#, 1]} & /@ l2
```

---

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
pi = PositionIndex[First /@ l1];
#/{1, 1, First@pi[First@#]} & /@ l2
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = Transpose[{Range[1980, 2010, 1], Range[31]}];
l2 = {{1990, 1, 100}, {2000, 2, 200}, {2010, 3, 300}};
```

Using `Cases` and `ReplacePart`:

```
ll = Cases[l1, s_ /; ! FreeQ[s, Alternatives @@ l2[[All, 1]]]];

ReplacePart[l2, {i_, 3} :> l2[[i, 3]]/ll[[i, 2]]]
```

> `{{1990, 1, 100/11}, {2000, 2, 200/21}, {2010, 3, 300/31}}`